# new to ubuntu - unable to work external montor on HP laptop

Tags: monitor

I'm just a regular Ubuntu user and wondering if someone can help me on how to make my external 19inch LED Dell monitor works via my HP Laptop HDMI. Thank you.

- OS: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS x86_64
- Host: HP Laptop 14s-dk0xxx
- CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 3500U with Radeon Vega Mobile Gfx (8) @ 2.100GHz
- GPU: AMD ATI Radeon Vega Series / Radeon Vega Mobile Series
- Memory: 2146MiB / 13878MiB

Below is the error

```shell
$ sudo apt-get install ./amdgpu-install_5.7.50700-1_all.deb 
[sudo] password for mykel: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'amdgpu-install' instead of './amdgpu-install_5.7.50700-1_all.deb'
amdgpu-install is already the newest version (5.7.50700-1653597.22.04).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up amdgpu-dkms (1:6.2.4.50700-1646729.22.04) ...
Removing old amdgpu-6.2.4-1646729.22.04 DKMS files...
Deleting module amdgpu-6.2.4-1646729.22.04 completely from the DKMS tree.
Loading new amdgpu-6.2.4-1646729.22.04 DKMS files...
Building for 6.2.0-36-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 6.2.0-36-generic
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/amdgpu-dkms.0.crash'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.2.0-36-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/6.2.4-1646729.22.04/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package amdgpu-dkms (--configure):
 installed amdgpu-dkms package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of amdgpu:
 amdgpu depends on amdgpu-dkms; however:
  Package amdgpu-dkms is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package amdgpu (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of amdgpu-pro:
 amdgpu-pro depends on amdgpu; however:
  Package amdgpu is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package amdgpu-pro (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of amdgpu-pro-lib32:
 amdgpu-pro-lib32 depends on amdgpu; however:
  Package amdgpu is not configured yet.
 amdgpu-pro-lib32 depends on amdgpu-pro (= 23.20-1646757.22.04); however:
  Package amdgpu-pro is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package amdgpu-pro-lib32 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                    No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                                                                  Errors were encountered while processing:
 amdgpu-dkms
 amdgpu
 amdgpu-pro
 amdgpu-pro-lib32
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1
```

Comment: How is the shown apt-get output related to te external monitor problem ?